# CGRectOffset not moving button to correct position

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, cgrect

I have a simple UIButton which when pressed, I would like it to move up the screen by 10 pts.

I have always used the below code to move images, iAds, etc... but for some reason its not working... It moves my UIButton to a position that I have NOT stated.

Here is my code:

```
my_button.frame = CGRectOffset(my_button.frame, 0.0, -10.0);
```

As you can see, I have added -10.0 to the y axis. So it should move the button up the screen by 10pts. For some reason, the app moves the UIButton to some postion on the left of the screen... this is odd..

I am not using Auto Layout if you are wandering.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: There may another piece of code that moves button to the undesired place.

Comment: Not sure about that. I don't think so. But I just cleaned and rebuilt my project and it started working as its supposed. I guess it was running an old version of my code. I just didn't realise it as the chain I was trying to make is really minor.